# Boost logging - logging in multiple files

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am using following code but I cant see any log file is generating. Can you please tell me why ? Also if anyone knows how to have logs in multiple files using severity logger please post the answer. Is it must to use channels also ?
Or the following code is enough to have logs in multiple file ?

```
src::severity_logger< severity_level > m_DbLogger;
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(tag_attr, "Tag", std::string)
logging::formatter fmt = expr::stream
<< std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << 1 << std::setfill(' ')
              << expr::if_(expr::has_attr(tag_attr))
              [
                  expr::stream << "[" << tag_attr << "] "
              ]
          << expr::smessage;
          // Initialize sinks
          typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;
          boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

          sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
              //boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >(m_Settings.LogFileSQL + ".log"));
              boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("1.log"));




          sink->set_formatter(fmt);
          sink->set_filter(!expr::has_attr(tag_attr));

          logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

          sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

          sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
              //boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >(m_Settings.LogFileSQL + "_diagnostics.log"));
              boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("2.log"));

          sink->set_formatter(fmt);

          sink->set_filter((expr::has_attr(tag_attr) && tag_attr == "IMPORTANT_MESSAGE"));

          logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

          // Add attributes
          logging::add_common_attributes();

          BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_DbLogger, severity_level::info) << "A regular message";
          BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_DbLogger, severity_level::info) << "Something bad is going on but I can handle it";
          BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_DbLogger, severity_level::info) << "Everything crumbles, shoot me now!";

          {
              BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG("Tag", "IMPORTANT_MESSAGE");
              BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_DbLogger, severity_level::info) << "An important message";
          }
```

Comment: I can generate the log files but only where my exe is. If I give a path other than exe path I cant create the log files. Do I need to add any macro or something to create log files at other place than where my exe is.

Comment: u have to add a simple code snippet which can be build